# How to communicate with VirtualBox NAT network from another device

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ping, nat, active-directory

Network scenario

[image]

Hi, I recently built an AD lab environment called GOAD on GitHub on my secondary PC (PL4YGR0UND) running Ubuntu 22.04 and I don't know how to communicate with VM's inside Virtualbox Network from my laptop (SP1RITB0X).

I can communicate with the secondary PC but not with the VirtualBox network.

I thought using port forwarding but I don't think it's a great solution because there are multiple services running so I'm not sure what can I do here or how to search for an accurate solution because it's a kinda tricky situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you wish to do (communicate with VM's inside Virtualbox Network  + multiple services), switch the Guest networking type to Bridged Networking. That will work much better and this is what I do and connections work just fine.

To enable network adapter bridged adapter in VirtualBox, you need to do the following:

> Shut down the Guest machine in question.
>
> Open VirtualBox and select your virtual machine.
>
> Click Settings and then click on the Network tab.
>
> Change the Networking Mode to Bridged.
>
> Start your guest machine.